# Python Unittest bug?

Tags: python, unit-testing

In this simple unittest, only one test case can be run.  When I comment out either test case, the remaining test runs, passes, and the module terminates normally.  When I allow both test cases to be run, the first case passes and the second case never terminates.  The module never terminates.  I created other modules with the same cases and each testcase can always run separately.

I cannot figure out what is going on, other than the remote possibility of a bizarre bug in unittest (usually not the right conclusion--my code is always the culprit).

```
from glob import glob
from email import message_from_string
from database import login_info
import maildb
import unittest

import mysql.connector as DBC

db = DBC.connect(**login_info)
curs = db.cursor()

TBLDEF = """
CREATE TABLE message (
    msgID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    msgMessageID VARCHAR(128),
    msgText LONGTEXT
    )"""
FILESPEC = "C:/PythonData/*.eml"

class testRealEmail_traffic(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """
        Reads arbitrary number of email messages and stores them
        in a brand new messages table.
        Destroys any previous table named message.
        """

        curs.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS message")
        db.commit()
        curs.execute(TBLDEF)
        db.commit()

        files = glob(FILESPEC)
        self.msgids = {}
        self.message_ids = {}
        for f in files:
            ff = open(f)
            text = ff.read()
            msg = message_from_string(text)
            id = self.msgids[msg['message-id']] = maildb.store(msg)
            self.message_ids[id] = msg['message-id']

    def test_not_empty(self):
        """
        Make sure the setUp method created messages and loaded the table.
        """
        curs.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message")
        messagecount = curs.fetchone()[0]
        self.assertGreater(messagecount, 0, "Database message table is empty")

    def test_a_test(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I think part of the problem is running this particular setUp between tests.  When I comment out the setUp (since there is no tearDown, the database remains), I can run multiple tests.

Comment: This suggests that I have been caught by the drop table takes hours in MySQL bug.

Comment: As it sounds like you're aware, setUp is run before *each* test. I would try adding print statements before each line in setUp and see which one it's getting stuck on.

Comment: How about a random table name? That would allow you to let MySQL drop the table in the background, which you trigger in `tearDown()`. Also, it looks wrong that `db` and `curs` are globals. I would have expected them to be created in `setUp()` and attached to `self` there. Having open connections and table references might cause overhead and slowdown in the DB, because it can't simply throw away the data. I must admit that I'm gleefully ignorant of MySQL though, so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: This is a metadata locking problem as described here: http://www.chriscalender.com/?tag=innodb-locks.   What is a little shocking is that even a select can cause metadata locking.  Wow!

Comment: @BrianRue: Did that--hangs on 2nd time round to drop the table--can't it's locked for metadata.  Could also tell that from looking at mysql via the console while code was running.  why does a simple select lock metadata?

Comment: @Ulrich: You are right about the globals.  db and curs needed to be in the setUp.  Also, the code being tested made connection to and cursor on the same db, also using globals.  Not sure where the problem really was, but this left sleeping processes in mysql.  Moving the connection and cursor creation into the actual functions solved the problem.  Anyone know when Python actually closes the connections?

Answer (score 0):

> You are right about the globals. db and curs needed to be in the setUp. Also, the code being tested made connection to and cursor on the same db, also using globals. Not sure where the problem really was, but this left sleeping processes in mysql. Moving the connection and cursor creation into the actual functions solved the problem.